# Clothing/body discrimination

Tags: discrimination, harassment, uniforms

My boss asked me to wear a size bigger in my scrubs because I looked too "sexy" and it's not to their liking in the work place.

I have a professional scrubs uniform. I can't help that I have a bust and hips!

So they made me go buy a new size for work and I'm flat broke now because of it!

Can they do this? Does this qualify as discrimination in any way?

Comment: Of course it qualifies as discrimination. Whether they can do it -- whether it qualifies as discrimination prohibited by law -- is something you probably need to take up with a lawyer, or take to law.stackexchange.com; IANAL.

Comment: We can't answer any legal question without a country/state tag. Labor laws vary widly around the globe.

Comment: When the discussion took place did you mention that this would cause financial hardship?  Rather than assuming harassment, you should assume that this person is being reasonable.  Give them an opportunity to accommodate you.  Perhaps they would allow you to pick up one new pair of scrubs per pay period.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. You should for instance provide the region of the world you are in, different regions of the world, have different rights that do or don't exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, if Hooters can make a tight uniform part of their "brand", I can't see that someone making looser uniforms standard is going to be forbidden, assuming the same standard is being applied to all employees. If anything, that should be easier for them to defend, given societal norms. I'm reminded of a new-hire briefing which included the statement "Sex is forbidden on company time and furniture. If you want to strut your stuff, do so away from work."

Answer (score 6):

Can the employer require a specific dress code at work, even a "uniform" of kinds? Yes, they can. Can they require you to wear a specific *size*? Yes, as long it it physically fits you, they can. In some jobs, that might even be required by law, because wrong sized clothing might be a safety risk. And it sounds like they want you to dress in a size *bigger* or two, so it doesn't seem like underhanded body shaming.

Is it discrimination? Well, that depends on the context. Are there others with the same problem that are allowed to do that? For example are men allowed to run around all day with pants so tight you can see the outline of things that should be left to after work activities between them and their significant other?

However, in any country with non-exploitative labor laws, if the employer has requirements to what their employees wear to work (whether it is a branded poloshirt, or scrubs or safety shoes or a suit) the employer either needs to pay for it directly, or needs to have an extra something on the paycheck in addition to normal salary that over time pays for it.

I will take a guess and say you live in a country where the employer can just exploit you this way and it is legal. That is bad. You need better labor laws. If you live in a democracy, find out who is on the ballot to fight for your rights so that your employer can not just force you to go broke from expenses you don't need.

In the mean time, you should talk to a union representative or a lawyer.

Generally speaking, not a workplace issue, but you should save up enough money so you can handle emergencies. Your uniform could have been damaged or stolen, you need to have *some* backup funds to not go broke from buying a new uniform.

Comment: too much generalizing.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with these sorts of claims is that the line between justifiable and discrimination is exceedingly blurry.

At one of the spectrum, you have a latex, skin-tight nurses outfit - a Company would be within their rights to ask that you wear something more appropriate.

On the other hand, you have someone dressed in conventional business casual who is asked to change - that's clearly not okay.

Do you have a claim? It's possible - I'm trying really hard not to crack the joke here of 'Pics or it didn't happen' - but the reality is that these sorts of cases are very subjective. What I consider smart business casual might not be what someone else considers it to be. What I consider merely 'a little snug', one might consider 'form fitting' and not appropriate, and the only way we could give an answer would be to see how tight fitting your attire was. If we, the humble strangers on the internet, think it's a bit too snug, then probably the business is in the right. If not, then you are possibly in the right...

**But all that is merely academic as it would be a Judge or a Jury that would ultimately decide if it was, indeed, too tight**

Sometimes you might have a case tangentially around it - not about the clothing being too tight, but the way and manner you were told about it (Telling someone at work they are too 'sexy' is always a minefield) - but you need to have proof it was said e.g. witnesses etc. - and even then - as above - it's very subjective.

The one thing that I would question - you mentioned Scrubs - so I'm presuming you work in the Medical field, in which case you may be able to raise it to the company to reimburse you as Scrubs can be considered PPE and PPE is provided by the company. Especially if you already had a set. At the very least, it may get your shortfall covered.

Comment: "On the other hand, you have someone dressed in conventional business casual who is asked to change - that's clearly not okay" I don't really understand that sentence. Assuming the OP needs to wear scrubs for work, showing up in business casual would prompt the boss to ask her to please change into scrubs.

Comment: Think of someone showing up to work in a suit jacket, blouse, black dress trousers - Smart business casual - being asked to change from that (assuming not in an area that requires specific uniform) would not be okay. But the point was to highlight the grey area.

Comment: The employer can regulate the dress code as they see fit. As long as there is no discrimination and the dress code affects everyone, they can absolutely say "everybody needs to wear shorts & shirts" There is no rule that the employer has to accept "smart business casual".

Comment: @nvoigt - Sure, but it would be an infinitely harder sell to claim someone was dressed inappropriately for work, if they were dressed in a manner that was typical for work.

Comment: Too minor to suggest as an edit: mindfield -> minefield